# TabBarViewController Scenes with Individual Right Bar Button Item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

How can I dynamically add a right bar button item to the sub-scenes associated with a TabBarController? The behavior I am looking for is, when I switch scenes.. I would like to dynamically change the bar button item. I am okay with having to change this in the TabBarViewController, but if I do.. how can I communicate that button press down to the appropriate controller to handle the action?

TabBarViewController (WORKS)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
}
```

StockTableViewController (DOES NOT WORK)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to wrap each tab controller into navigation controller?

Comment: @SergeyGamayunov I actually have a use case for this. If you could provide a solution I'd be eternally grateful. I've tried doing it before but ended up doing it manually in IB.

Comment: why are you embedded a tabor within a navigation controller, that's not supposed to work  like that, what's you case

Comment: I think you need to not use a navigation controller in combination with a tabBarController. I would suggest using tabBarController and creating a custom navigation

Comment: I basically had a navigation controller >> Login / Register Scenes >> Tab View Controller >> Multiple Scenes

Comment: when login is done you don't need to push the uitababar just present it, is nit recommended to return to login by just making a back button, if you have a logout button you can set the rootviewController to the windows propertie or use the one in the appDelegate.